# Assigning values to attributes in the background during form submission with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller

I have a form on a page that a user can use to create a course. While I understand how to get provide the user the opportunity to fill in simple things like the course name and description, I also want to assign the user's id to a teacher_id column. This should be done automatically for the user and they shouldn't see an opportunity to assign a teacher_id as it should be their id.

Currently the "Create a course" page's view is this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'My Classes') %>
<h1>Create a class!</h1>

<div class="row">
   <div class="span6 offset3">
     <%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, :size => "30x6" %>

      <!-- Assign the current user's id to the teacher_id column in the background -->

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the new action in the course controller looks like:

```
def new
    @course = Course.new
end
```

What's the best way to accomplish what I want to do? I'm pretty new to Rails and I haven't had much experience with forms and all the possibilities. I read a little bit on the hidden_field_tag but I don't know if that's the kind of thing I need and I was finding it difficult to get the user's id in the form anyway. Do I need to make a user instance variable in the controller or can I do it with code in the view somehow.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field):

```
<% provide(:title, 'My Classes') %>
 <h1>Create a class!</h1>

<div class="row">
   <div class="span6 offset3">
     <%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, :size => "30x6" %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, :value => :current_user.id %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** - to explain how to have the `current_user` available in the form.

I normally have a `session` controller that is responsible for login and logout users, creating a `session` to keep the user logged in.

The create action for example:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:success] = "Welcome " + current_user.name
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid username/password combination."
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

If the combination of username and password are correct, it will create a `session` with the `user_id` (`session[:user_id]`).
Now, in your `application_controller` you can have something like the below:

```
private
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

The `helper_method` allows you to use the `current_user` in any controller or view in your application.

I hope it helps....

Comment: if the `teacher_id` attribute exists in your `Course` model, and the current_user is accessible from your view, you don't need to change your controller....

Comment: where would the current_user originate from and how can I make it accessible?

Comment: I think I got it to work by using `@user = current_user` in the courses controller and with `:value => @user.id %>.`

Comment: Unfortunately now I need to work out: `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

Comment: I don't know how you are keeping a user logged in... do you have a controller `session`? you need to define the `current_user` in your application controller, so it will be available for all controllers and views. I will edit my answer to try to help you...

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have a create action like:

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(params[:course])
end
```

Assuming you have the variable for the @current_user available, you should be able to set that in the controller before you save the new Course.

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(params[:course])
  @course.teacher_id = @current_user.id
  @course.save
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @course.id
end
```